# How to invalidate timer outside ViewDidLoad

Tags: ios, swift, timer, nstimer

I'm stuck with invalidating timer outside of ViewDidLoad. Tried to declare timer globally, but got a SIGABRT error. What am am I missing?

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    let timer = Timer(timeInterval: 3, 
                      target: self, 
                      selector: #selector(updateOnlineTrack), 
                      userInfo: nil, 
                      repeats: true)

    RunLoop.current.add(timer, forMode: .defaultRunLoopMode)
    timer.fire()

}
```

updateOnlineTrack is marked with @objc and project is compiling, but I can't figure out this SIGABRT

```
@objc private func updateOnlineTrack() {

    print("Tick")

}
```

Basically I need to invalidate timer and stop updating, when user leaves current View Controller.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare `timer` as an instance property instead of a local variable.

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    var timer: Timer?

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 3, 
                  target: self, 
                  selector: #selector(updateOnlineTrack), 
                  userInfo: nil, 
                  repeats: true)

        timer?.fire()
    }
}
```

Note that it is optional.

Note the use of `scheduledTimer`. This is simpler than adding it to a runloop yourself.

Comment: Thank you! Now I'm stuck with which answer to accept)

Comment: You are free to decide. Pick the answer that best answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

The timer is fired automatically when you init it after the specified interval  , you can declare it like this

```
var timer:timer?
```

//

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    self.timer = Timer(timeInterval: 3, 
                  target: self, 
                  selector: #selector(updateOnlineTrack), 
                  userInfo: nil, 
                  repeats: true)

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that solves it. I definitely need to pause)